# Clipping multiple resampled rasters to same size using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, clip, snapping, resampling

I have various rasters of environmental variables that were imported as GeoTiffs or NetCDFs. The rasters had varying cell size which I fixed by resampling them using the `Snap Raster` function in `Environments > Output Extent` to ensure that the cell borders of all rasters match up.

So far so good.

However, when I now try to clip all rasters to a rectangluar polygon some of the clipped rasters have an additional row or column, i.e. the clipped rasters have different row or colum sizes.

How do I clip all rasters to the same size using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3?

Answer (score 2):

Truns out, all I needed to do was using `Spatial Analyst > Extract By Mask` instead of `Clip`.